# Probability distribution of durations

Tags: r, time-series, distributions, survival

I'm struggling conceptually with something:

If I had two simulation outputs that had dates and counts of outcomes of those dates, could I then create a probability distribution of time distances between these two outputs?

I am aware of concepts like divergence but not sure how I could apply them in practice to distributions of dates.

Or is what I am asking actually impossible?

I have provided an R dput of some data:

```
structure(list(Date=structure(c(27347,27360,27374,27375,
27379,27380,27389,27400,27403,27407,27409,27413,27415,
27423,27427,27428,27430,27431,27434,27435,27436,27437,
27438,27441,27442,27443,27444,27448,27450,27452,27455,
27456,27457,27458,27459,27463,27464,27465,27466,27469,
27470,27471,27472,27477,27478,27479,27480,27483,27484,
27485,27486,27487,27490,27491,27492,27493,27494,27497,
27498,27499,27500,27505,27506,27507,27508,27511,27513,
27514,27515,27519,27521,27522,27525,27526,27527,27528,
27529,27532,27533,27534,27535,27536,27540,27541,27542,
27543,27546,27547,27548,27549,27550,27553,27554,27555,
27556,27557,27561,27562,27563,27564,27567,27568,27569,
27570,27571,27574,27575,27576,27577,27578,27581,27582,
27583,27584,27585,27588,27589,27590,27591,27592,27595,
27596,27597,27598,27599,27602,27603,27604,27605,27606,
27609,27610,27611,27612,27613,27616,27617,27618,27619,
27620,27623,27624,27625,27626,27627,27631,27632,27633,
27634,27637,27638,27639,27640,27641,27644,27645,27646,
27647,27648,27651,27652,27653,27654,27655,27658,27659,
27660,27661,27662,27665,27666,27667,27668,27669,27672,
27673,27674,27675,27676,27679,27680,27681,27682,27683,
27686,27687,27688,27689,27690,27693,27694,27695,27696,
27697,27700,27701,27702,27703,27704,27707,27708,27709,
27710,27711,27714,27715,27716,27717,27718,27721,27722,
27723,27724,27725,27728,27729,27730,27731,27732,27735,
27736,27737,27738,27739,27742,27743,27744,27745,27746,
27749,27750,27751,27756,27757,27758,27760,27763,27764,
27765,27766,27767,27770,27771,27772,27773,27774,27777,
27778,27779,27780,27781,27784,27785,27786,27787,27788,
27791,27792,27793,27794,27795,27798,27799,27800,27801,
27802,27805,27806,27807,27808,27809,27812,27813,27814,
27815,27816,27819,27820,27821,27822,27823,27826,27827,
27828,27829,27830,27833,27834,27835,27836,27837,27840,
27841,27842,27843,27844,27847,27848,27849,27850),class="Date"),
Hits=structure(c(2L,2L,13L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,13L,
2L,2L,2L,13L,13L,2L,2L,13L,2L,2L,2L,2L,25L,25L,
35L,2L,2L,13L,13L,13L,2L,13L,34L,13L,25L,13L,
36L,25L,2L,2L,13L,34L,2L,2L,25L,2L,13L,13L,25L,
34L,25L,25L,34L,2L,25L,25L,35L,2L,25L,13L,2L,
13L,2L,25L,2L,34L,2L,2L,36L,25L,25L,2L,2L,2L,
13L,13L,36L,25L,35L,2L,13L,25L,34L,34L,25L,13L,
25L,25L,25L,13L,34L,34L,34L,13L,13L,34L,34L,25L,
36L,35L,34L,34L,25L,35L,25L,3L,36L,3L,25L,37L,
13L,37L,36L,25L,25L,3L,6L,35L,39L,36L,13L,37L,
35L,38L,25L,38L,38L,39L,25L,39L,35L,34L,38L,38L,
38L,3L,6L,25L,9L,3L,38L,5L,38L,34L,4L,35L,5L,
6L,36L,3L,10L,6L,37L,3L,8L,36L,4L,35L,4L,6L,
8L,39L,3L,37L,6L,7L,3L,36L,10L,3L,4L,14L,7L,
7L,5L,6L,11L,11L,7L,6L,39L,6L,5L,36L,15L,11L,
16L,6L,6L,6L,12L,39L,9L,10L,14L,7L,8L,15L,37L,
9L,7L,15L,7L,7L,10L,19L,11L,9L,10L,11L,10L,12L,
15L,11L,6L,39L,6L,18L,18L,14L,22L,9L,14L,12L,
38L,7L,14L,9L,12L,6L,4L,14L,11L,12L,10L,10L,6L,
14L,11L,21L,9L,10L,10L,18L,19L,10L,14L,26L,16L,
17L,14L,11L,16L,14L,17L,15L,20L,21L,20L,11L,26L,
17L,15L,12L,20L,11L,15L,16L,12L,18L,20L,20L,10L,
22L,19L,22L,24L,17L,20L,20L,17L,10L,17L,19L,16L,
21L,19L,17L,17L,33L,10L,22L,19L,20L,11L,14L,16L,
17L,15L,14L),.Label=c("","1","10","11","12","13",
"14","15","16","17","18","19","2","20","21","22",
"23","24","25","26","27","28","28/02/2024","29","3",
"30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","4","5",
"6","7","8","9","Hits","LVL1-4350"),class="factor"),
cumhits=structure(c(2L,108L,241L,298L,350L,404L,467L,
552L,3L,24L,37L,48L,58L,78L,98L,109L,117L,133L,
140L,148L,156L,162L,180L,199L,228L,235L,242L,254L,
266L,277L,282L,292L,313L,323L,339L,351L,381L,399L,
405L,412L,424L,447L,453L,461L,482L,490L,505L,524L,
553L,599L,652L,4L,8L,9L,12L,15L,20L,21L,25L,27L,
29L,31L,33L,36L,38L,42L,43L,45L,50L,53L,55L,57L,
59L,61L,64L,66L,70L,72L,76L,79L,81L,84L,88L,91L,
93L,96L,99L,102L,104L,106L,111L,114L,118L,120L,
122L,125L,128L,130L,135L,137L,141L,144L,146L,151L,
153L,159L,164L,169L,171L,175L,177L,182L,185L,187L,
190L,195L,202L,205L,210L,214L,216L,220L,223L,226L,
229L,234L,239L,245L,248L,252L,256L,259L,263L,268L,
272L,278L,285L,287L,294L,300L,304L,309L,314L,316L,
321L,325L,331L,337L,341L,346L,355L,361L,365L,369L,
378L,382L,388L,391L,397L,406L,416L,420L,427L,430L,
438L,445L,451L,456L,469L,476L,484L,498L,512L,525L,
534L,546L,566L,586L,608L,627L,645L,679L,727L,763L,
6L,7L,10L,11L,13L,14L,16L,17L,18L,19L,22L,23L,
26L,28L,30L,32L,34L,35L,39L,40L,41L,44L,46L,47L,
49L,51L,52L,54L,56L,60L,62L,63L,65L,67L,68L,69L,
71L,73L,74L,75L,77L,80L,82L,83L,85L,86L,87L,89L,
90L,92L,94L,95L,97L,100L,101L,103L,105L,107L,110L,
112L,113L,115L,116L,119L,121L,123L,124L,126L,127L,
129L,131L,132L,134L,136L,138L,139L,142L,143L,145L,
147L,149L,150L,152L,154L,155L,157L,158L,160L,161L,
163L,165L,166L,167L,168L,170L,172L,173L,174L,176L,
178L,179L,181L,183L,184L,186L,188L,189L,191L,192L,
193L,194L,196L,197L,198L,200L,201L),.Label=c("",
"1","10","100","10000","1019","1037","104","105",
"1059","1072","108","1085","1098","111","1117","1126",
"1142","1159","116","117","1179","1193","12","120",
"1208","122","1229","123","1236","125","1252","126",
"1266","1287","129","13","130","1301","1315","1332",
"134","135","1357","136","1375","1391","14","1408",
"142","1426","1443","145","1462","148","1483","149",
"15","150","1501","151","1514","1523","153","1536",
"155","1560","1584","1604","161","1632","164","1648",
"1668","1687","169","1695","17","170","1709","172",
"1729","1745","175","1764","1777","1788","179","1808",
"1826","183","1845","186","1862","1879","188","1892",
"19","191","1912","1930","194","1957","197","1973",
"199","1990","2","20","2007","203","2031","2056",
"207","2073","2093","21","211","2123","213","2145",
"215","2168","2188","219","2206","2228","223","2248",
"226","2271","2292","23","2318","232","2345","237",
"2371","2389","24","241","2419","2442","245","2463",
"248","2482","25","2508","2526","253","2547","256",
"2569","2588","26","2612","2638","266","2664","2681",
"27","2709","272","2734","2762","2791","2814","282",
"2840","285","2866","2889","2906","292","2929","294",
"2954","2976","30","3003","301","3028","3051","307",
"3074","310","3111","3128","313","3156","3181","3207",
"3225","323","3245","3267","3290","33","3311","3331",
"336","3361","3383","341","3417","3436","3456","3479",
"350","3506","3531","3555","356","3577","358","3601",
"3621","3647","365","3670","3697","370","3723","3756",
"378","3788","38","381","3814","3834","3859","3883",
"389","39","3911","3933","3955","397","3985","4",
"40","4018","4043","406","4065","4088","409","4110",
"4136","4158","418","4186","42","4220","423","4239",
"4257","427","4277","4313","4339","435","4365","4394",
"44","4418","443","4446","4470","4491","451","4520",
"4548","4567","4592","46","461","4622","4648","4676",
"47","4708","4737","474","4763","477","4794","4826",
"4856","4884","49","4911","493","4931","4957","4986",
"5","5006","503","5038","5064","5092","511","5129",
"5158","5189","5212","523","5242","5267","5299","53",
"531","5331","535","5364","5387","5423","5449","546",
"5477","55","5508","551","5526","5546","5573","5596",
"5623","563","5651","5674","5702","5723","5749","576",
"5772","58","5800","582","5836","5857","5880","5909",
"592","5940","5965","5987","6","60","6011","6043",
"6070","609","6091","6117","6139","6167","6201","622",
"6224","6244","6277","629","6308","6338","6370","639",
"6391","6408","6431","6451","6470","6496","6514","6538",
"654","6570","6590","66","660","6620","6639","6660",
"6683","6701","671","6723","6743","676","6766","6795",
"6815","6844","6863","687","6883","69","6909","6942",
"6965","6988","7","70","700","7011","7026","7047",
"7065","7081","71","7105","7131","7149","715","7177",
"7189","7222","724","7246","7264","7289","73","7314",
"7336","734","7355","7388","741","7411","7425","7448",
"7463","7484","7504","7526","754","7548","7573","7590",
"7616","7637","7672","768","7689","77","7711","7740",
"7768","778","7787","78","7805","7818","784","7840",
"7857","7874","7883","79","7906","7931","7946","7969",
"7992","8","8004","801","8018","8037","8055","8071",
"8085","8098","811","8115","8134","8150","8170","8192",
"82","8209","822","8223","8243","8268","8283","8299",
"83","8313","8331","8349","8364","8380","8393","8404",
"842","8423","8438","8448","8461","8478","8492","85",
"8504","8519","8530","8539","8546","8559","856","8572",
"8583","8598","8612","8622","8631","8645","8665","8675",
"8686","8695","87","870","8707","8728","8741","8755",
"8769","8785","8799","8809","882","8824","8834","8847",
"8859","8876","8885","8897","8910","8925","8935","8949",
"895","8959","8971","8981","8985","8994","9","90",
"9006","9017","9026","9033","9048","9058","9072","9075",
"9086","9102","9114","9128","913","9143","9151","9157",
"9169","9177","9183","9191","9197","9208","9216","9226",
"9236","9244","9252","9259","9270","9286","9293","9300",
"931","9310","9319","9329","9334","9343","9355","9362",
"9372","9382","9389","9393","9399","94","9405","9416",
"9423","9428","9437","9439","9442","9446","945","9458",
"9463","9473","9481","9485","9490","9496","9501","9511",
"9518","9524","9531","9535","9543","9551","9555","9564",
"9568","958","9580","9586","9592","9596","9602","9606",
"9613","9619","9623","9630","9636","9643","9649","9653",
"9657","9662","9666","967","9674","9677","9683","9688",
"9692","9697","97","9702","9711","9714","9720","9723",
"9727","9730","9735","9740","9745","9748","9752","9756",
"9760","9765","9770","9772","9776","9781","9782","9785",
"9788","9791","9794","9795","9797","980","9801","9803",
"9805","9811","9813","9818","9823","9827","9831","9834",
"9837","9844","9848","9850","9852","9853","9856","9858",
"9863","9865","9868","9870","9871","9875","9881","9885",
"9887","9888","9889","9890","9892","9896","9897","9899",
"9900","9901","9902","9904","9905","9907","9910","9911",
"9912","9913","9914","9916","9919","992","9920","9921",
"9923","9925","9926","9927","9929","9932","9934","9935",
"9937","9939","9941","9943","9944","9945","9948","9950",
"9953","9954","9955","9956","9959","9961","9962","9963",
"9965","9966","9969","9971","9973","9975","9976","9978",
"9979","998","9980","9981","9982","9983","9984","9985",
"9986","9987","9988","9989","9990","9991","9992","9993",
"9994","9995","9996","9997","9998","9999","CumulativeHits",
"MainPlan"),class="factor"),
Date2=structure(c(34652,34665,34679,34680,34684,34685,
34694,34705,34708,34712,34714,34718,34720,34728,34732,
34733,34735,34736,34739,34740,34741,34742,34743,34746,
34747,34748,34749,34753,34755,34757,34760,34761,34762,
34763,34764,34768,34769,34770,34771,34774,34775,34776,
34777,34782,34783,34784,34785,34788,34789,34790,34791,
34792,34795,34796,34797,34798,34799,34802,34803,34804,
34805,34810,34811,34812,34813,34816,34818,34819,34820,
34824,34826,34827,34830,34831,34832,34833,34834,34837,
34838,34839,34840,34841,34845,34846,34847,34848,34851,
34852,34853,34854,34855,34858,34859,34860,34861,34862,
34866,34867,34868,34869,34872,34873,34874,34875,34876,
34879,34880,34881,34882,34883,34886,34887,34888,34889,
34890,34893,34894,34895,34896,34897,34900,34901,34902,
34903,34904,34907,34908,34909,34910,34911,34914,34915,
34916,34917,34918,34921,34922,34923,34924,34925,34928,
34929,34930,34931,34932,34936,34937,34938,34939,34942,
34943,34944,34945,34946,34949,34950,34951,34952,34953,
34956,34957,34958,34959,34960,34963,34964,34965,34966,
34967,34970,34971,34972,34973,34974,34977,34978,34979,
34980,34981,34984,34985,34986,34987,34988,34991,34992,
34993,34994,34995,34998,34999,35000,35001,35002,35005,
35006,35007,35008,35009,35012,35013,35014,35015,35016,
35019,35020,35021,35022,35023,35026,35027,35028,35029,
35030,35033,35034,35035,35036,35037,35040,35041,35042,
35043,35044,35047,35048,35049,35050,35051,35054,35055,
35056,35061,35062,35063,35065,35068,35069,35070,35071,
35072,35075,35076,35077,35078,35079,35082,35083,35084,
35085,35086,35089,35090,35091,35092,35093,35096,35097,
35098,35099,35100,35103,35104,35105,35106,35107,35110,
35111,35112,35113,35114,35117,35118,35119,35120,35121,
35124,35125,35126,35127,35128,35131,35132,35133,35134,
35135,35138,35139,35140,35141,35142,35145,35146,35147,
35148,35149,35152,35153,35154,35155),class="Date"),
hits2=structure(c(2L,2L,2L,2L,13L,2L,2L,2L,2L,
2L,13L,2L,13L,2L,2L,2L,2L,13L,2L,24L,2L,2L,13L,
13L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,13L,13L,24L,13L,2L,24L,2L,
2L,13L,2L,13L,2L,2L,36L,2L,13L,2L,2L,35L,35L,
24L,35L,24L,36L,13L,13L,13L,35L,13L,13L,35L,24L,
36L,2L,2L,2L,2L,36L,2L,24L,35L,24L,13L,24L,13L,
36L,35L,13L,13L,24L,38L,35L,35L,24L,35L,37L,35L,
36L,37L,35L,38L,24L,13L,37L,36L,35L,35L,36L,37L,
39L,37L,40L,37L,38L,38L,24L,39L,24L,37L,24L,38L,
4L,24L,4L,37L,37L,36L,39L,40L,3L,36L,37L,7L,36L,
5L,4L,40L,39L,4L,38L,36L,39L,36L,36L,3L,10L,36L,
4L,5L,24L,40L,37L,40L,39L,40L,40L,39L,3L,5L,3L,
39L,40L,4L,7L,38L,3L,3L,4L,8L,4L,8L,4L,4L,38L,
4L,14L,5L,8L,6L,4L,5L,40L,9L,3L,11L,39L,3L,8L,
8L,39L,6L,7L,8L,15L,40L,8L,16L,14L,8L,9L,39L,
12L,14L,40L,6L,11L,14L,8L,14L,8L,12L,5L,5L,11L,
11L,12L,15L,7L,10L,10L,3L,15L,14L,10L,5L,21L,
17L,12L,10L,22L,15L,19L,16L,19L,14L,10L,22L,14L,
17L,16L,11L,19L,4L,14L,17L,21L,5L,11L,7L,11L,
11L,9L,11L,12L,7L,17L,11L,11L,20L,19L,10L,18L,
18L,5L,17L,16L,20L,21L,9L,28L,12L,17L,14L,19L,
9L,14L,19L,10L,15L,15L,21L,10L,17L,21L,23L,19L,
25L,16L,19L,25L,14L,21L,16L,18L,22L,15L,14L,16L,
12L,27L,16L,26L,6L,16L,26L,17L,26L,8L,18L,19L,
18L),.Label=c("","1","10","11","12","13","14","15",
"16","17","18","19","2","20","21","22","23","24",
"25","26","27","28","29","3","30","31","32","33",
"34","35","36","37","38","39","4","5","6","7","8",
"9","EntirePlan","Hits"),class="factor"),cumhits2=structure(c(2L,
98L,170L,235L,347L,404L,470L,553L,3L,15L,37L,47L,
67L,74L,83L,90L,99L,116L,123L,144L,151L,158L,171L,
184L,191L,198L,204L,210L,218L,228L,241L,255L,266L,
272L,290L,296L,302L,313L,318L,328L,335L,341L,368L,
374L,387L,392L,397L,423L,448L,471L,498L,524L,574L,
602L,634L,685L,7L,9L,11L,16L,18L,23L,24L,26L,27L,
29L,33L,35L,39L,42L,45L,48L,51L,53L,58L,61L,63L,
65L,68L,72L,76L,79L,81L,85L,89L,93L,97L,102L,106L,
111L,114L,117L,120L,125L,127L,131L,134L,137L,142L,
147L,153L,157L,161L,165L,167L,173L,176L,179L,182L,
187L,193L,195L,202L,207L,211L,215L,220L,224L,230L,
233L,237L,244L,247L,252L,258L,263L,268L,274L,278L,
281L,285L,288L,292L,298L,306L,310L,316L,322L,324L,
329L,332L,338L,343L,349L,353L,357L,362L,369L,375L,
379L,384L,391L,400L,405L,411L,417L,424L,433L,441L,
450L,458L,465L,472L,478L,493L,501L,513L,527L,537L,
548L,557L,575L,588L,614L,626L,646L,689L,757L,5L,
6L,8L,10L,12L,13L,14L,17L,19L,20L,21L,22L,25L,
28L,30L,31L,32L,34L,36L,38L,40L,41L,43L,44L,46L,
49L,50L,52L,54L,55L,56L,57L,59L,60L,62L,64L,66L,
69L,70L,71L,73L,75L,77L,78L,80L,82L,84L,86L,87L,
88L,91L,92L,94L,95L,96L,100L,101L,103L,104L,105L,
107L,108L,109L,110L,112L,113L,115L,118L,119L,121L,
122L,124L,126L,128L,129L,130L,132L,133L,135L,136L,
138L,139L,140L,141L,143L,145L,146L,148L,149L,150L,
152L,154L,155L,156L,159L,160L,162L,163L,164L,166L,
168L,169L,172L,174L,175L,177L,178L,180L,181L,183L,
185L,186L,188L,189L,190L,192L,194L,196L,197L,199L,
200L,201L),.Label=c("","1","10","10000","1004","1017",
"102","1031","104","1046","106","1067","1076","1091",
"11","110","1113","113","1133","1148","1164","1172",
"118","119","1191","120","121","1211","122","1220",
"1233","1251","127","1271","128","1286","13","1306",
"131","1321","1340","135","1352","1364","138","1382",
"14","140","1400","1419","143","1440","145","1454",
"1471","1488","1498","150","1519","1539","154","1556",
"156","1568","158","1595","16","161","1618","1637",
"1654","168","1682","17","1703","172","1728","1750",
"176","1775","179","1795","18","1812","183","1840",
"1860","1883","189","19","1905","1923","193","1948",
"1959","1979","198","2","20","2002","2029","204",
"2041","2059","2073","208","2091","2109","2125","2143",
"215","2162","2176","218","2199","22","220","2217",
"2235","226","2261","2286","23","2303","231","2327",
"235","2351","2363","2386","239","2408","2434","244",
"2461","2477","250","2510","2529","2552","2572","258",
"2597","26","2613","2633","264","2658","2675","2696",
"27","2717","273","2744","2761","2784","279","28",
"2811","2840","286","2865","2895","2917","293","2942",
"296","2972","2992","3","30","3019","304","3041",
"3065","307","3093","3114","313","3134","3156","316",
"3175","32","3207","3229","323","3260","3273","3295",
"33","3326","334","3349","337","3380","3395","34",
"3419","3444","3468","348","3492","35","3510","3528",
"354","3554","3576","36","360","3603","3618","3641",
"365","3669","3696","37","3716","373","3743","3764",
"3794","382","3821","3838","3875","39","3906","392",
"3940","3954","397","3979","4","4005","403","4039",
"4070","4096","41","4127","4160","417","4196","4218",
"422","4253","4281","4307","4328","434","4348","4381",
"44","4410","4432","445","4457","4480","4513","4531",
"454","4552","4577","46","4604","462","4637","4663",
"4691","47","4709","473","4737","4776","4798","480",
"4822","4844","485","4867","4899","4925","493","4943",
"4965","498","4998","50","5016","503","5041","5069",
"5084","51","5105","513","5130","5158","5184","52",
"5211","5243","5278","530","5300","5324","5347","535",
"5371","5391","54","5412","5450","546","5479","55",
"5507","5540","5564","558","5597","561","5625","5652",
"5686","57","570","5716","5740","576","5766","5796",
"58","5821","5839","585","5867","5887","59","5915",
"593","5945","5969","5991","6","6019","602","6043",
"6075","6104","611","6128","6154","6174","619","6195",
"6223","6249","6275","629","6295","6320","6345","6359",
"6386","64","641","6415","6443","6467","6497","65",
"651","6522","6550","6580","659","6604","6631","6645",
"6664","668","6682","6697","67","6723","6751","6774",
"679","68","6803","6829","6860","6873","69","6901",
"6913","693","6942","6966","6990","7","700","7009",
"7030","7048","7072","7089","710","7107","7125","7142",
"7160","7179","720","7202","7229","7255","7271","7297",
"73","731","7322","7345","7361","7373","7393","7408",
"7428","7441","746","7462","7481","7496","7514","7535",
"7555","7568","757","7591","7608","7625","7641","7663",
"7688","77","7708","772","7723","7735","7751","7768",
"7788","7806","7819","783","7846","7859","7880","7896",
"7920","7937","794","7955","7968","7984","7999","8",
"80","801","8019","8037","8056","8079","8099","812",
"8121","8138","8154","8168","8183","8193","8203","8222",
"8237","8254","8271","8290","8299","8311","832","8330",
"8352","8375","8392","84","8407","8427","844","8448",
"8465","8476","8489","8501","8522","8531","8547","8558",
"8571","8582","859","8595","8607","8626","8635","8649",
"8663","8671","8680","8692","8699","87","8706","8717",
"872","8724","8736","8754","8767","8778","8789","8800",
"8816","8829","883","8839","8851","8860","8873","8886",
"8898","8909","8919","8934","8947","895","8959","8969",
"8987","8994","9","9014","9020","9029","904","9041",
"9046","9060","9068","9077","9084","9095","9108","9116",
"9122","9130","9142","9151","9166","9180","9189","92",
"920","9204","9211","9217","9231","9236","9243","9249",
"9254","9267","9277","9291","9296","930","9308","9315",
"9323","9334","9341","9349","9358","9369","9375","9379",
"9383","9388","9397","94","9400","9410","9415","9426",
"9435","9438","9444","9451","9459","9468","9476","948",
"9488","9493","9497","9503","9512","9519","9524","9533",
"9540","9544","9553","956","9562","9568","9575","9581",
"9586","9591","9598","96","9602","9606","9611","9615",
"9621","9627","9632","9637","9641","9650","9659","966",
"9668","9672","9673","9676","9681","9685","9688","9692",
"9694","9699","9706","9710","9713","9720","9726","9728",
"9732","9738","9743","9748","9749","9752","9755","9760",
"9762","9766","9771","9775","9781","9782","9785","9787",
"9791","9792","9793","9794","9798","9799","98","9800",
"9805","9808","981","9810","9812","9814","9820","9823",
"9826","9828","9830","9834","9842","9847","9849","9852",
"9854","9855","9857","9859","9860","9861","9864","9868",
"9871","9872","9874","9876","9879","9882","9885","9886",
"9887","9888","9890","9892","9897","9900","9901","9902",
"9905","9906","9908","9910","9913","9914","9915","9916",
"9917","9919","9922","9923","9925","9928","9929","9930",
"9932","9934","9936","9938","9939","9940","9942","9943",
"9945","9948","9952","9956","9957","9958","996","9960",
"9962","9963","9964","9965","9967","9968","9969","9970",
"9971","9972","9973","9974","9975","9976","9977","9979",
"9980","9981","9982","9983","9984","9986","9987","9988",
"9989","9990","9991","9992","9993","9994","9995","9996",
"9997","9998","9999","CumulativeHits","scn2"
),class="factor")),.Names=c("Date","Hits","cumhits",
"Date2","hits2","cumhits2"),row.names=8:307,class="data.frame")
```